# Jitpack and kotlin multiplatform artifact groupId

Tags: gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, jitpack

I made project in kotlin multiplatform and I configured it to be deployable through jitpack.
When I publish it to maven local repository and access it through "mavenLocal()" repositories in gradle, everything works as expected.
Ex:

```
implementation "com.github.hovi:kotlintools-f:$kotlintools_version" //main meta for "common module"
implementation "com.github.hovi:kotlintools-jvm:$kotlintools_version" //jvm dependency, etc
```

However when I remove `mavenLocal()` repository and swap it for jitpack, I cannot find the repository.
If you take a look at jitpackbuild, everything in log seems fine at first:

```
Found artifact: com.github.hovi:kotlintools-android-debug:0.0.20
Found artifact: com.github.hovi:kotlintools-android:0.0.20
Found artifact: com.github.hovi:kotlintools-js:0.0.20
Found artifact: com.github.hovi:kotlintools-jvm:0.0.20
Found artifact: com.github.hovi:kotlintools-f:0.0.20
Found artifact: com.github.hovi:kotlintools-metadata:0.0.20
```

However later there's:

```
com.github.hovi.kotlintools:kotlintools-metadata:0.0.20
com.github.hovi.kotlintools:kotlintools-jvm:0.0.20
com.github.hovi.kotlintools:kotlintools-android:0.0.20
com.github.hovi.kotlintools:kotlintools-android-debug:0.0.20
com.github.hovi.kotlintools:kotlintools-f:0.0.20
com.github.hovi.kotlintools:kotlintools-js:0.0.20
```

So `kotlintools` is added to groupId and is doubled.

When I access artifact using this doubled group-id is kind of somehow works in a way that I can reference it, but some of the meta build functionality is very confused and broken.

Overall it just is broken and doesn't work or just barely builds in command line while IDEA is full of red error messages. So I naturally want to be able to reference it from jitpack same way as it works from my mavenlocal.

What is the cause of this? Am I configuring something incorrectly on jitpack/gradle/kotlin-multoplatform? It's all on github:
https://github.com/hovi/kotlintools

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Jitpack is not compatible with KMP and the gradle metadata dependency scheme they're using. I don't have a lot of detail on *why* it isn't working, but you should look into bintray or sonatype/maven central.